# Junction table Trigger after update in another table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions

I'm just trying to create a trigger that performs an update in a junction table.

In principle, I have three tables with Many-to-Many relationship.

```
Table a:
a_id, a_is_active
Table b:
b_id, b_is_active
Table ab:
ab_id, a_id, b_id, ab_is_active
```

What I want is that the `ab_is_active` needs to be actualized when `a_is_active` or `b_is_active` is updated, so `ab_is_active` should be like this (pseudo code):

`ab_is_active = a_is_acvite && b_is_acvite where a_id = a.a_id and b_id = b.b_id`

and that must be carried out after each `is_active` update in Table a or in Table b:

I have tried the following, but it does not work (nothing is updated in ab):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_active_changes()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    b_is_active boolean;
    r            b%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    for r in select *
             into b_is_active 
             from ab
                      join b _b on ab.b_id= _b.b_id
                      join a _a on ab.a_id= _a.a_id
        LOOP
                update ab set ab_is_active = r.a_is_active and r.b_is_active where b_id = r.b_id and a_id = r.a_id;
        END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;

create trigger is_active_trigger
    after update
    on a
    for each row
execute procedure is_active_changes();
```

Can someone tell me what I do wrong or suggest a better solution?

Comment: you do understand that the loop will run for every updated row over and over again

Comment: But the ab_is_active is not changed, there are no changes in the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is , that you made  some small errors

in the for loop you need to select those columns that fit the rowtype

I added as last a Version that is better as it only update one row and not all where b.id and a.id are present

> ```
> CREATE Table a
> ("a_id" INT, "a_is_active" Boolean)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE Table b
> ("b_id" INT, "b_is_active" Boolean)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE Table ab
> ("ab_id" INT , "a_id" int, "b_id" int, "ab_is_active" Boolean)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO a VALUES (1,TRUE)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO B VALUES (1,TRUE)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO ab VALUES (1,1,1,FALSE)
> ```

> ```
> DO
> $BODY$
> DECLARE
>     b_is_active boolean;
>     r            ab%ROWTYPE;
> BEGIN
>     for r in select ab.ab_id, ab.b_id,ab.a_id,_a.a_is_active AND _b.b_is_active AS ab_is_active
>              from ab
>                       join b _b on ab.b_id= _b.b_id
>                       join a _a on ab.a_id= _a.a_id
>         LOOP
>                 update ab set ab_is_active = r.ab_is_active 
>                 where b_id = r.b_id AND a_id = r.a_id;
>         END LOOP;
> END;
> $BODY$;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ab
> ```
>
> ```
> ab_id | a_id | b_id | ab_is_active
> ----: | ---: | ---: | :-----------
>     1 |    1 |    1 | t
> ```

> ```
> DO
> $BODY$
> DECLARE
>     b_is_active boolean;
>     r            ab%ROWTYPE;
> BEGIN
>     for r in select ab.ab_id, ab.b_id,ab.a_id,_a.a_is_active AND _b.b_is_active AS ab_is_active
>              from ab
>                       join b _b on ab.b_id= _b.b_id
>                       join a _a on ab.a_id= _a.a_id
>         LOOP
>                 update ab set ab_is_active = r.ab_is_active 
>                 where ab_id = r.ab_id;
>         END LOOP;
> END;
> $BODY$;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7c8f45b14d4b384511ba5dea49ae1544)*

Comment: I found my mistake. thank you!